# Removing CheckBoxList crashes page (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I am working with a form that was previously built. I'm trying to remove a CheckBoxList that was already there. I don't need it on this form.

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList TabIndex="6" ID="ddlSchool" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Item">Item</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList></div>
```

...and when I remove it, I get this...

[Render after CheckBoxList is removed](https://www.box.com/s/2e5s39kzrqra859d9udr)

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If all else fails, set visible=false. Use code or CSS. Nothing can break with this...

Comment: If I set it to invisible in the CSS, then it's not going to show up on any of the other forms either.

Comment: Since it is specific to this page.[pseudo code](Style="Visible:false") or something in that line will take care of that particular instance.

Comment: I'm trying to apply a pseudo element in Visual Stuio, but it's not working... I'm laying it out the same way I would in html. Is that right?

Comment: You are right. It did not work. But this works <asp:CheckBoxList TabIndex="6" ID="ddlSchool" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" Visible="false">. I tried it out by putting this code in Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {this.ddlSchool.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; }. This code did not break when Visible="false".

Comment: Using css to fix a compiler error is an awful workaround. It doesn't solve the actual problem and no one ends up any wiser at the end of the day.

Comment: You must be mistaken. If you really read the question, you will realize that I PREVENTED the problem not FIX it. Rather than DELETING a control (which caused the problem), simply HIDE it!!! Why mark me down? The BEST battles are those NEVER fought!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove any code that references this list. Search for ddlSchool in your code-behind file (projectHelpRequest.aspx.cs) and comment out the lines that give you error...

Comment: This is my aspx.cs file... I am not showing what you're identifying...  
`using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
  
public partial class ContentRequest_NewName : System.Web.UI.Page  
{  
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
  
    }  
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you created this NewName.aspx file, did you copy/paste the content from another file?

The error screen is telling you everything you need to know. Your NewName.aspx page is using the code behind for ProjectHelpRequest.aspx, not NewName.aspx. ProjectHelpRequest's code behind references ddlSchools, so by deleting it from NewName.aspx you're getting an error about it missing.

You need to make sure that in the directive at the top of NewName.aspx that you're setting the CodeBehind and/or Inherits values to inherit from NewName, not ProjectHelpRequest.

Comment: I did just copy and paste... I'm new to this type of development... so, I've got a bit of a learning curve. It appears I have a lot to learn... but I learn fast.